# How to plot triangles on a 6x6 grid in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, graph, geometry

I have a file **a.txt** which is like:

```
0 0 0 3 4 3
0 0 3 0 3 4
0 1 0 4 4 4
0 1 3 1 3 5
0 2 0 5 4 5
0 3 0 0 4 0
```

These are vertices of triangles [x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3] that I need to plot on a 6x6 grid.
I need to see these triangles on a single graph.

How can this be done in MATLAB?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
thanks a lot everyone!

finally what worked:

```
a = dlmread('a.txt');

clf
xlim([0 6])
ylim([0 6])
for i = 1:size(a,1)

   line(a(i,[1:2:5,1]), a(i,[2:2:6,2]), 'color',rand(1,3))
   pause;

end
grid on;
```

Comment: i am still searching. cannot find any triangle function in matlab... also one problem is that the graph gets automatically truncated near the highest values, how to get it fixed at 6x6?

Comment: The auto setting of limits really deserves its own question.  It is best to keep these questions focused. (using XLIM and YLIM will help though!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = dlmread('a.txt')
clf

for i = 1:size(a,1)
    line(a(i,[1:2:5,1]), a(i,[2:2:6,2]), 'color',rand(1,3))
end
```

Notice that I am repeating the vertice to complete the triangle and the I am using a random color each time through the loop.

Because the format is easy, I can use DLMREAD with defaults.

Comment: thanks @MatlabDoug, how can I make it pause for a keypress after adding a triangle to the image?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [PATCH](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/patch.html) function to accomplish this, although many of the triangles you have specified lay on top of one another:

```
a = [0 0 0 3 4 3; ...  % A variable "a" containing the data from the file
     0 0 3 0 3 4; ...
     0 1 0 4 4 4; ...
     0 1 3 1 3 5; ...
     0 2 0 5 4 5; ...
     0 3 0 0 4 0];
x = a(:,[1 3 5])';  % Get the x coordinates, one set per column
y = a(:,[2 4 6])';  % Get the y coordinates, one set per column
patch(x,y,'r');     % Use patch to plot one triangle per column, colored red
```

Comment: most of the triangles I have are overlapping, so patch() will not be that useful, unless it can display the triangles one by one, say after pausing for a keypress?

Comment: Perhaps adding the third dimension might help:

patch(x,y, repmat(1:size(a,1),3,1), 'r'); 
view(3)