# How to call MATLAB code from C?

Tags: c, matlab, matlab-deployment

I have some [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506243/how-to-plot-triangles-on-a-6x6-grid-in-matlab) that plots triangles in MATLAB.

I need to be able to somehow execute this code from my C program which generates these points.

**Is that possible? How can it be done?**

**Just a thought:**
Can I somehow embed MATLAB code in C, so that it can compile on a C compiler?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Mathworks site has [full details](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f38569.html&http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/helptoc.html); a [demo video](http://fr.mathworks.com/videos/calling-matlab-from-c-code-68913.html) of calling the Matlab engine from C, and also the [Matlab to C Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/rtwembedded/).

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned previously by answerers, you can call a live copy of MATLAB from C via the [MATLAB Engine](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f38569.html&http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/helptoc.html) interface.

If the end-product needs to be used where there is no live copy of MATLAB, you can deploy the application using [MATLAB Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/). However, MATLAB Compiler does not, as another answer has suggested, convert MATLAB programs into C code (and hasn't done for a few versions now). Instead, it archives and encrypts your MATLAB program, and packages it into an executable or shared library that executes against the MATLAB Compiler Runtime (shareable royalty-free). The executable or shared library can then be called from C.

Alternatively you could go the other way around, and call your C code from MATLAB, using either [loadlibrary](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/loadlibrary.html) or MATLAB's [MEX interface](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/bp_kqh7.html).

Update: As of release R2011a, you can also use [MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder) to generate C code directly from a subset of the MATLAB language.

Comment: I linked to the wrong product - generating C code from Matlab is fairly fundamental to how it's used in many industries.

Comment: Yes - if you want to generate C code from MATLAB for embedded applications, you can do that using the emlc command. This requires that you also have both Simulink and Real-Time Workshop, though (not MATLAB Compiler), and that seems like overkill in order to plot points of a triangle :)

Comment: update: MathWorks now have a new product: [MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this presentation about integrating MATLAB Algorithms in C or C++ Applications http://www.mathworks.com/videos/integrating-matlab-algorithms-in-c-or-c-applications-86431.html

Comment: Hi! Answers, if referencing a link, should contain essential parts of a link, as links can break and no longer be accessable.