# integrating Matlab and C

Tags: c, matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call MATLAB code from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513583/how-to-call-matlab-code-from-c)

I feel like an idiot for asking so many question, but i don't know who else to ask.
so, i have an audio sample (in an 1d array). Now the audio array was captured using C code, what i would like to do is call matlab's FFT,and spectrogram functions. and i would like it to be a stand alone C application. meaning it doesn't require matlab.
how would i do this?

i found this:[MATLAB CONVERT](http://engr.nmsu.edu/~etti/5_1/5_1f/5_1f.html)
but i keep on getting erros saying compiler not found, even though i do mbuild -setup to get the MSVC++ compiler, i am not so sure what the error is. (i don't know if this is revelent but i am on a x64 comp)

Also converting matlab code to C stand alone application..would that work for even gui's in matlab

Comment: I recommend using [fftw](http://www.fftw.org/), a C library.

Comment: i though of doing this, get the data from microphone (done), then appy fft using fftw. then finally plot using matlab's specgram function. will that be fine?